# Single word meaning a statement which is proving itself wrong

Tags: single-word-requests

Eg.

> Saline water does not contain salt.

So it is a **__** statement. What is the word that should fill in the blank?

This statement is clearly making itself wrong in its later part. What should it be called?

Comment: Bad example as it is a good sentence. One could extend it:  'Saline water does not contain salt, it contains disolved salt ions.'

Comment: I wrote it casually. Did not think to the deep!

Comment: So, we need a word for a statement which at first sight looks wrong, but is actually correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like *self-refuting*.

- *self-contradictory* and *self-refuting* imply an logical contradiction
- *oxymoron* implies only a surface contradiction, like *the living dead* or *jumbo shrimp*
- *paradoxical* implies a genuine question about its truth value

Answer (score 11):

*Incongruous*, *inconsistent*, or *paradoxical* is sufficient.

Answer (score 10):

It is said to be *self-contradictory*.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to a couple points here...

*Oxymoron(ic)* can only be used in reference to a phrase - I think only a noun phrase - but not to a *statement*. And officially, I think, it should be used when the apparent contradiction is resolved when you understand what the phrase is referring to. (Like, the first time you hear "living dead" you're like, "WTF? Ohhhhhh... it's zombies!" And then it makes sense.") If it's really not resolvable, but is just an error, like "free-market communist", then it would be a *contradiction in terms.* (Though in common usage, I think you can use *oxymoron* for both.)

For a complete statement, you could use simply use *self-contradictory*, *self-negating*... I actually stumbled here looking for the same thing. I'm sure there's a cool latin phrase somewhere...

Answer (score -2):

Another word for a self-contradictory statement is *oxymoron*.

Comment: **NO!** A self-contradictory statement contains an error (in meaning). An oxymoron is a paradox, a statement etc that appears to contain a self-contradiction but makes sense on deeper analysis, encapsulated in a very few words. There is a vast difference.