# Regarding Trump's "being, like, really smart" statement. What is it called when the content of statement is contradicted by its composition?

Tags: oxymoron, contradiction

Trump's recent tweet about his mental stability and genius like intelligence, made me wonder.

What's it called when someone makes a statement that appears to be a contradiction like this:

> ....Actually, throughout my life, my two greatest assets have been mental stability and being, like, really smart. Crooked Hillary Clinton also played these cards very hard and, as everyone knows, went down in flames. I went from VERY successful businessman, to top T.V. Star.....

in particular.

> ...and being, like, really smart.

Seems like a contradiction in terms.

I suppose a similar example:

> I am too, really smart.

or

> I'm a freakin' geneeos.

and so on.

Comment: Skitt’s law was obeyed by this post. (“It’s” isn’t used for possession)

Comment: _Self-refuting_, _self-contradictory_? [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96782/single-word-meaning-a-statement-which-is-proving-itself-wrong) is along the same lines.

Comment: _Saline water does not contain salt._ is explicitly self contradictory/refuting.  I was hoping for a concept that was more specific to the implicit contradiction that is displayed by Trump.

Comment: I am curious about this question. Would there be a word like this in the English language? One that would describe a person that is contradicting its words through actions or performance? It could work in the opposite direction too. A person that is trying to pass as dumb or stupid but its behavior or vocabulary give it away.

Comment: Duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96782/single-word-meaning-a-statement-which-is-proving-itself-wrong ?

Comment: @fralau - I don't think it's a duplicate.  Nothing explicit in the wording suggests this phrase is contradicting itself.  `Saline doesn't contain salt` is a direct contradiction.  This is a different case.

Comment: @ocodo Could you explain why and how your question differs from the one on [Saline water?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96782/single-word-meaning-a-statement-which-is-proving-itself-wrong) From what I see, the case/question may be somewhat different, but they could result in the same answers.

Comment: The contradiction is in the wording of 'Saline doesn't contain salt' ... There's an explicit contradiction.   Trump saying he's **'like, really smart'** contradicts himself more implicitly, I assumed English was complex enough to express this difference.  Perhaps I'm wrong, but I hope that there is a better answer than simply self contradictory.

Comment: "Oxymoron", of course.  Or perhaps "moron's ox".

Comment: Unintended irony.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "a performative contradiction".

Performative words are words that are also actions. The classic case, from J.L.Austin, are the words "I do" in a marriage ceremony. Said at the appropriate moment by an appropriate person, these are not simply words, but are also an action because the have the effect of contracting a marriage. In the context of the Trump tweet it can be plausibly argued that the words say one thing ("I am really smart") but act in a way that demonstrates the opposite.

Note, however, that the character of performativity depends on context. In the case of the marriage ceremony, if the person saying "I do" is already married, then at least in principle the words don't have the effect of contracting the marriage. The Trump tweet, inserted as it is into a politically contentious context, will be performatively contradictory for some, but not for others. Differently, it could also be argued that it is not performatively contradictory because it reveals (say) lack of education rather than lack of brain power.

Answer (score 0):

You might call these statements **[self-defeating](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+self-defeating)**:

> (of an action or policy) unable, because of its inherent qualities, to achieve the end it is designed to bring about.